# Custom Testimonial page

Tags: views

I need to make a testimonial page, which include 3 parts.

1. text on the above
2. video testimonial which have the owner name and his image
3. text testimonial which have the owner name and his image

I am new at Drupal and using Drupal 7 for start things.

I made 2 content types, first for video testimonials the second for text testimonials

Now I am confused how i will proceed to plan things up.

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: There are many ways of doing this,  can you attach a picture of exactly what you want,  then we can gear our answer towards this

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways. But i suggest that you do it with [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

In this [video tutorial](http://blip.tv/bao-truong/drupal-panels-demo-home-page-3306777) you can see exactly how you can do what you asked for.

You can spice up your testimonial page by adding [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) displaying random testimonials.